# Multiple Errors serving HTML pages with Express

Tags: express

I'm trying to route pages using Express, but I can't seem to route from my main page. I'm using HTML as the view engine and I feel like everything is set up properly, but I'm seeing the error:
"TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile"

Here is my file structure:

```
root
-public
--images
--index.html
--main.css
--sponsors.html
--team.html
app.js
```

I've tried multiple file routes, res.render versus res.sendFile.

```
var express = require("express")
var app = express()
const port = 3000
var http = require("http")
const path = require('path')
app.set("view engine", "html")

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port 
${port}!`))

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/sponsors', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('sponsors')
  })

  app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index')
  })

  app.get('/team', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('team')
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

To render from a view engine, use `res.render()`, not `res.sendFile()`.

And, your view engine will need to be able to find a file with that name and an appropriate file extension in the path for the view engine.

If you want to use `res.sendFile()` without the view engine, then you must specify an actual filename or include the `root` option that tells it where to look.  You must also use the actual file extension on the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following route method.

```
// remove the following code
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.sendFile('index')
});
```

Update the default path to the static method you had already written.

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```